# Funcion eliminar arbol binario en C

Tags: c

Al implementar la función me da un error de segmentación el cual lo busque y dice que es porque intento acceder a memoria que no tengo permitido usar, he intentado varias cosas pero siempre es lo mismo, solo es esta función ya que el resto de código si funciona correctamente.

```
void borrar(nodo_arbol*nodo,int valor){
if(nodo){
    if(nodo->valor==valor){
        if(nodo->padre){
            if(!nodo->derecho && !nodo->izquierdo){

            }else if(!nodo->derecho && nodo->izquierdo){
                if(nodo->valor>nodo->padre->valor){
                    nodo->padre->derecho=nodo->izquierdo;

                }else{
                    nodo->padre->izquierdo=nodo->izquierdo;

                }

            }else if(nodo->derecho && !nodo->izquierdo){
                if(nodo->valor>nodo->padre->valor){
                    nodo->padre->derecho=nodo->derecho;

                }else{
                    nodo->padre->izquierdo=nodo->derecho;

                }

        }else if(nodo->derecho && nodo->izquierdo){
                if(nodo->valor>nodo->padre->valor){
                    nodo->padre->derecho=nodo->derecho;

                }else{
                    nodo->padre->izquierdo=nodo->derecho;

                }
                nodo->izquierdo->padre=nodo->derecho;
        }
        free(nodo);
        printf("valor eliminado");
}else{
    nodo->izquierdo->padre=nodo->derecho;
    free(nodo);
}
    }else{

            if(nodo->valor>valor){
                borrar(nodo->derecho,valor);
            }else{
                borrar(nodo->izquierdo,valor);
            }
        }
    }else{
        printf("valor no encontrado");
    }
}
```

La función es recursiva pero de todos modos debe funcionar, soy nuevo en C por lo que no se si estoy haciendo algo incorrecto.

Comment: Te recomiendo algo para estos casos difíciles: Depurar.

Comment: Además de que explicases tus pesquisas depurando como dice @SuperG280, podría ayudar a comprender el problema que nos compartieras el uso que le das a la función que falla.